# I tried to make a basic vehicle rotation code with unity input manager, but it does not react

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I wrote a code that should allow me to rotate the "GameObject Vehicle" by pressing the "A" "D" keys, I wrote this code according to the official course from Unity.
Working code before changes:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 10f;
    public float turnSpeed = 0f;

    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    void Update()
    {
        transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime * speed);
        transform.Translate(Vector3.right * Time.deltaTime * turnSpeed);
    }
}
```

Code after changes:

```
using System.Collections;

using System.Collections.Generic;

using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour

{

    public float speed = 10f;

    public float turnSpeed = 0f;

    public float horizontalInput;

    void Start()

    {

        

    }

    void Update()

    {

        horizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

        transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime * speed);

        transform.Translate(Vector3.right * Time.deltaTime * turnSpeed * horizontalInput);

    }

}
```

The compiler (in my case Microsoft Visual studio) shows that the code is absolutely correct.  Unity reacts exactly the same way. However, after adding Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");  In addition to not giving any response to key presses, it also removed any response to changing the turnSpeed ​​parameter through the Unity interface.

I restarted Unity and also tried completely removing the code file from the project and then creating it again, but it didn't help.  The code should change the direction of the "Vehicle" object according to the pressed "A" or "D" key.

Comment: in the first set of code, how did A and D do anything? in the second one, turn speed is 0, so it wont turn for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your broken code if your turn speed is 0 you will have no effect with A and D. When you are not holding down A or D `horizontalInput` value is 0. That is why it wipes out the `turnSpeed` effect. In either of these cases you are multiplying by zero and get zero output.

Make sure that turnSpeed is set to a non-zero value in the editor.
Make sure that horizontalInput is not set in the editor.
Make sure you are actively holding A or D, not just pressing it once.

Comment: Thank you! Changing turnSpeed solved the problem.